# Is it possible to update the UI from the backgroundworker dowork event

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have seen others with a similar issue but not quite what I was looking for.  In the backgrounderworker class dowork event I create an instance of a new class and call one of it's function.  Previously, I had this code in a windows.form.timer tick event and would pass a delegate in as one of the parameters which would allow the function and other functions it calls within the class to call a method on the form to update a datagrid on the GUI.  Is there a way to do this within the dowork event?  I need this because the function I call from dowork calls other functions and I want each of those functions to log information in the GUI datagrid.

Answer (score 5):

The BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress() method was intended to do that.  You implement the ProgressChanged event to update the UI, it will run on the main thread.  You're not restricted to report just a progress percentage, you can pass any object as well to pass info to the event handler by using the overload that accepts the *userState* argument.  Beware that you have to use proper locking if you do that.

Comment: Don't forget to set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `true` on the background worker itself.

Comment: Here is the issue I am having with using ReportProgress.  In DoWork, I make a call to a function.  That function makes calls to other functions.  I want all those functions to be able to send status updates to the UI.

Comment: So, write a function that calls ReportProgress so that all these other functions can call it.  Pass a delegate if you have to.  Be careful, the thread marshaling is very expensive.  Call it more than ~1000 times per second and the UI thread goes dead when it can't keep up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `ReportProgess` mentioned in Hans' answer, you can alternatively use [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) on one of the UI elements to exeute code in the UI thread.

Comment: But in DoWork, can I pass this ability (as a delegate parameter) to a class I instanstiate in DoWork?

Comment: @user94593: Control.Invoke's MSDN page (see the link in my answer) contains an example at the end.

Comment: @user94593: The second overload, which allows you to pass parameters, might be interesting for you as well (again, example is included at the bottom): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can send progress data back to the UI thread, you will get an event for that on the UI thread, then you can update the screen. It is **highly preferred** that the objects you send back to the UI thread are immutable. Besides calling the `ReportProgress` and handling the event you need to opt-in by setting `WorkerSupportsProgress` property to true.